# Does the XPath collection () function work with lxml and XSLT?

Tags: python, xml, xslt, xpath, lxml

I tried recently to transform an XML file with the lxml package and a XSL stylesheet containing a variable with XPath collection() function however I get the following error when i'm running my code:

```
lxml.etree.XSLTApplyError: Failed to evaluate the expression of variable 'name'.
```

Here are the details of my files:

- XML source : catalog.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <collection>
         <doc href="./IR_041698.xml"/>
         <doc href="./IR_051379.xml"/>
     </collection>
```

- XSL file : test.xsl

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="tei">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

     <xsl:variable name="name" select="collection('catalog.xml')/descendant::archdesc/did/origination/persname/text()"/>

     <teiHeader xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
                    <fileDesc>
                        <titleStmt>
                            <title>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
                            </title>
                       </titleStmt>
                   </fileDesc>
      </teiHeader>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

- Python code :

```
from lxml import etree as ET

source = ET.parse("catalog.xml")
xslt = ET.parse("test.xsl")

transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(source)

print(ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True))
```

I am a little bit surprised because when I launched the transformation under Oxygen XML editor it works but not in Python.

Do you have any suggestions ? Is XPath collection() function a problem with lxml?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `collection` function is part of XPath and XSLT 2 and later and as such not supported by lxml. You can however, in XSLT, use the `document` function as `document(document('catalog.xml')/*/doc/@href))` to select the "collection" of documents selected by the `href` attributes of the `doc` element nodes in the catalog.xml document.

Saxon 9.9 is also available as a Python module https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc/html/saxonc.html as part of Saxon C 1.2.1 (Download http://saxonica.com/download/c.xml, documentation: http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation/index.html) so you might consider switching from lxml to Saxon-C if you want to use XSLT 3 in Python.